# I have an input box and hidden field. I want to pass the value of text box to hidden filed. How to achieve that

Tags: asp.net

I have an input box and hidden field. I want to pass the value of text box to hidden filed. How to achieve that.

Comment: Assign the value via an ID reference to the control - or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
myhiddenfield.Value = mytextbox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) asp.net controls
    hiddenField.Text = textbox.Text;
OR
    hiddenField.value = hiddenField.value;

(if you have runat="server" in the non-asp.net control tag.)

2)Jquery:

```
 jquery $('#hiddenField').val() = $('#textboxid').val();
```